# c# MVC post not populating view model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a ViewModel which has a property defined as an IList of type Division. The Division object is as follows:

```
public class DivisionViewModel :
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int DivisionId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

In the past, I have just created the following in the View:

```
<div class="divisions">
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Divisions.Count(); i++)
    {
        @Html.Hidden(Model.Divisions[i].DivisionId.ToString(), new { @name = "Divisions[" + i + "].DivisionId", @id = "Divisions_" + i + "__.DivisionId" })
        @Html.Hidden(Model.Divisions[i].Id.ToString(), new { @name = "Divisions[" + i + "].Id", @id = "Divisions_" + i + "__.Id" })
        @Html.Hidden(Model.Divisions[i].Name, new { @name = "Divisions[" + i + "].Name", @id = "Divisions_" + i + "__.Name" })
    }
</div>
```

When I submit the page, on checking the returned ViewModel, I find that the DivisionId is populated, but both the Id and Name property is not.

I have commented out the line that sets the DivisionId, but it is still returned without the Id and Name properties

What have I missed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most common cause for model binding failing is that the `name` attributes of your inputs do not match the names of the properties in your model, and the first thing you should always do is inspect the html your code is actually generating. Assuming the value of the `DivisionId` in the first item is `1`, what you are generating is

```
<input name="1" type="hidden" value="{ @name = Divisions[0].DivisionId, @id = "Divisions_0__.DivisionId }" />
```

which has no relationship to your model.

- The 1st parameter is the property to bind to, and you are telling it
  to bind to a property named `1` - the result of `Model.Divisions[i].DivisionId.ToString()`, which does not exist, and is illegal
  anyway
- The 2nd parameter of `@Html.Hidden()` is the `value` of the property,
  so your telling it to use your anonymous object as the value
- Even if you added the 2nd parameter (so that the html attributes
  would be generated from the anonymous object), it would still not work since using
  `@name="..."` fortunately does nothing at all - the purpose of using
  the `HtmlHelper` methods is to correctly bind to your model)

Just use

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Divisions.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Divisions[i].DivisionId)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Divisions[i].Id)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Divisions[i].Name)
}
```

And the correct name and value attributes will be generated for binding to your collection.

Having said that, all you have are hidden inputs, so it makes no sense to generate all that extra html, send it to the browser and send it all back again unchanged. If you need that collection in the POST method, then just get it from your repository.

As a side note, your `new { @id = ".." }` makes no sense. The purpose of adding an `id` attribute is for use in css and javascript/jquery selectors, which do not really make sense for collection items, but in any case would not work because you have a `.` (dot) which would act as a class name selector